# axios is not sending X-CSRFToken header in production

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have Django rest deployed on Heroku with domain like: `api.herokuapp.com`.

On front end I have React with domain like: `dashboard.mydomain.com`

Settings for axios are:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
```

Locally everything works fine.

In production:
Making POST request I am getting 403 error:

> CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Seeing at request there is cookie sent:

[image]

but it's not sending `X-CSRFToken` header.

Locally it's sending the header normally.

I suspect it could be either because production is HTTPS or because domains are different, but I don't know much about it.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
```

Comment: thanks, do you get token with js-cookie package or you hardcode?

Comment: i extracted the code sent from backend.You can upvote if you like the answer.

Comment: This won't work if the cookie is HttpOnly